# How to define right-to-left subtitles in SSA/ASS format

Tags: subtitles, matroska

I am editing an [SSA/ASS file](https://www.matroska.org/technical/specs/subtitles/ssa.html) with the following options:

```
[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,Tahoma,24,&H00FFFFFF,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,0.00,1,2,20,20,20,1
```

What option can I use to make the subtitle right-to-left and enable writing complex scripts (like a combination of Farsi and English)?

Answer (score 1):

well, all you need is to have arabic/farsi font and subtitle editor which supports such inputs - http://www.aegisub.org/downloads/

[image]

```
[Script Info]
; Script generated by Aegisub 3.2.2
; http://www.aegisub.org/
Title: Default Aegisub file
ScriptType: v4.00+
WrapStyle: 0
ScaledBorderAndShadow: yes
YCbCr Matrix: None
PlayResX: 640
PlayResY: 480

[Aegisub Project Garbage]
Last Style Storage: Default
Video File: ?dummy:23.976000:40000:640:480:47:163:254:
Video AR Value: 1.333333
Video Zoom Percent: 0.750000
Video Position: 362

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: OP,Boahmed Alhour,40,&H00E9CCB9,&H000000FF,&H00BA632C,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,1.5,0.5,2,23,23,23,1
Style: Default,Boahmed Alhour,40,&H00E9CCB9,&H000000FF,&H00BA632C,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,1.5,0.5,2,23,23,23,1

[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:05.25,0:00:15.12,OP,,0,0,0,,إن عزمت على المسير فلا بأس أن تكون هنا Hello
```